# How to jump from Azure B2C Owin login to the AD graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I try to modify  Azure B2C users' information from my site. I am new to Azure B2C and I followed this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi sample to understand how to log my user with B2C. That work great. But I can't find a way to use a token or claims received with the login to be able to call the AD Graph API to change some information on the client.

In the sample I got this function called after a sucessfull login:

```
        /*
     * Callback function when an authorization code is received 
     */
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
    {
        // Extract the code from the response notification
        var code = notification.Code;

        string signedInUserID = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, notification.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, Scopes);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Handle
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But what next? The sample I found on the graph API do not use this king of login.

Here the OWIN login config:

```
        /*
    * Configure the OWIN middleware 
    */
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
                MetadataAddress = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy),

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = ClientId,
                RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,

                // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                },

                // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                },

                // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
                Scope = $"openid profile offline_access {ReadTasksScope} {WriteTasksScope}"
            }
        );
    }
```

dd

Answer (score 1):

Because an Azure AD B2C Application does not have access to the Azure AD Graph API.

Call it a feature GAP.

Today, the only way to access the Azrue AD B2C Graph API, is by registering a separate application under `Azure Active Directory` and **not** `Azure Active Directory B2C`. Same portal, same user, same `Directory`. Do not change the "Directory". Just navigate to the "real" Azure AD. There under `App registrations` just make a new app registration, grant it `application` permissions to `Windows Azure Active Directory`, generate a `key` and use the [Client Credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) in your web api backend.

This is the only way today to use Graph API in B2C. And this is also basically [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet).

Comment: Well. Ok so I need to change the OWIN authentication process for a ADAL one to be able to ask for a token for the graph API? Owin middleware take in charge the change password, edit users personal info, etc.. So I like the simplicity of the OWIN login (I update the question with the Login part of the owin). If I understand the basic description that you post, I can't use any information returned by OWIN login to ask a Graph Token...